# Sending RabbitMq messages between Docker containers using docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, pika

So my goal is to have several containers that interact among themselves using rabbitmq messages(rabbitmq server is in a separate container)

rabbit.py

```
class Rabbit:
    host = 'rabbitmq-host'
    userid = 'test'
    password = 'test'


class Consumer(Rabbit):

    def __init__(self, exchange_name):
        self.exchange_name = exchange_name
        self.connection = None
        try:
            credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(self.userid, self.password)
            params = pika.ConnectionParameters(self.host, 5672, '/', credentials)
            self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            if self.connection is not None and self.connection.is_open:
                self.connection.close()
            raise ex

        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
```

Credentials test:test exist, I re-checked.

Then from another file(main.py) the Consumer is created

```
c = Consumer('media')
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

rabbitmq-server:
  image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
  hostname: "rabbitmq-host"
  environment:
    RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: "SWQOKODSQALRPCLNMEQG"
    RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "test"
    RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "test"
    RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: "/"
  ports:
    - "15672:15672"
    - "5672:5672"
  labels:
    NAME: "rabbitmq1"


info-getter:
  build: ./info-getter
  depends_on:
    - rabbitmq-server
  tty: true
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
```

When testing, I run rabbitmq server in a container, but the app from local mechine, all is working, but when I run 'docker-compose up' I get this exception:

```
info-getter_1      | 
info-getter_1      | Traceback (most recent call last):
info-getter_1      |   File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
info-getter_1      |     c = Consumer('media')
info-getter_1      |   File "libs/rabbit.py", line 27, in __init__
info-getter_1      |     raise ex
info-getter_1      |   File "libs/rabbit.py", line 22, in __init__
info-getter_1      |     self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
info-getter_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 360, in __init__
info-getter_1      |     self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
info-getter_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 451, in _create_connection
info-getter_1      |     raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
info-getter_1      | pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError
services_info-getter_1 exited with code 1
```

Where am I going wrong?

Also I would like to add that even though I have 'depends_on' specified, after I run 'docker-compose up' the info-getter log appears before the rabbitmq-server log.

Answer (score 4):

The host needs to be the name you defined in docker-compose.yml:

```
my-worker:
    image: my-worker-image
    restart: always
    depends_on:
        - my-rabbitmq
my-rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    ports:
    - 5672:5672
    - 15672:15672
```

then in your consumer (python):

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('my-rabbitmq'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually the error message contains additional status - for example:

> pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError: Connection to
>   :5672 failed: **[Errno 111]** Connection refused

This error is caused usually because the RabbitMQ workers/clients failed to connect to the RabbitMQ-server. 
This might happen from a number of reasons - I'll name a few:

1) The IP of the RabbitMQ-server wasn't specified correctly.
It might no passed has a environment variable (this is why its important to add a check for that in the code). 
When working with [docker-compose](/questions/tagged/docker-compose) the IP of the RabbitMQ-server should be replaced with the service DNS (which is the name of the service in the `docker-compose.yml` file or the value of `hostname` property if specified).

2) The RabbitMQ workers/clients tried to reach the RabbitMQ-server before its ready. 
**Notice that `depend_on` only express dependency between services, and wait for services to *start* but not to be *ready***. 
So you can't rely on it by adding:

```
  depends_on:
    - rabbitmq-server
```

Because the RabbitMQ-server service bootstrap phase take time.
See the reference below regarding the `depend_on` command.
See the solutions I provided for this runtime dependency problem below.

3) There is a RabbitMQ-server service already running on the host which uses the `5672` port. 
In this case you'll receive an explicit error when you try to start the RabbitMQ-server service, but from the RabbitMQ-worker perspective its the same problem.

---

You can solve the runtime dependency problem mentioned in the #2 by:

A) Had a retry logic in the client - Consider using [pluggins](https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html#federation-and-shovel) like [Shoval](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html) and [Federation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/federation.html).

B) If the cause for the problem is #2 - you can use the [restart_policy](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart_policy) option and the connection will succeed after a few retries.

C) Use a tool such as [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it), [dockerize](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize), or sh-compatible [wait-for](https://github.com/Eficode/wait-for). 
 These are small wrapper scripts which you can include in your application’s image to poll a given host and port until it’s accepting TCP connections. Read more in [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/).

D) Execute `docker-compose up rabbitmq-server` and only after service is ready execute the other services.

E) Use a time interval (e.g `sleep 10`) in the workers execution command (I won't recommend this approach).

---

Regarding from `depends_on` from the [Docker-Compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on):

There are several things to be aware of when using `depends_on`:

> `depends_on` does not wait for db and redis to be “ready” before
>   starting web - only until they have been started. If you need to wait
>   for a service to be ready, see Controlling startup order for more on
>   this problem and strategies for solving it. 
>  
>   Version 3 no longer
>   supports the condition form of `depends_on`. 
>  
>   The `depends_on` option is
>   ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with a version 3 Compose
>   file.

Answer (score 2):

I've also faced with this problem. And the point is that `pika` library doesn't understand such kind of host names without any domain like plain `rabbitmq`.

So, you can add a host alias to your RabbitMQ compose service, for example, I changed host to `rabbitmq.com` and it started working:

```
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.3-management
    domainname: rabbitmq.com
    ports:
      - 5672:5672   # The standard AMQP protocol port
      - 15672:15672 # HTTP management UI
```

And use like `connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host="rabbitmq.com"))`

I've also tried to change host to `rabbitmq.local` but that didn't work either :)

Another possible, solution is to use your host network for your application service (because you've already exposed your Rabbit ports to the host).

```
info-getter:
  build: ./info-getter
  depends_on:
    - rabbitmq-server
  tty: true
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  network_mode: host
```

In this case, you should set `localhost` as host value in your pika connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the host to `rabbitmq-server` -

```
class Rabbit:
    host = 'rabbitmq-server'
    userid = 'test'
```

Comment: tried, same result. However web interface of the rabbitmq tells me that the host is rabbitmq-host